# UICollectionView setting spaces between section

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I've a UICollectionView which shows rows of cell which are circle. At even rows, I would like the entire section to have a margin-left.

The layout would then be something like this:

```
O O O O O
 O O O O
O O O O O
```

Do I have to subclass the flow layout or are there an easier way out?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, no.

One approach could be manipulation the fist cells(in every row) widths at even rows..

```
 ...    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row%2==0 && indexPath.column==0)
        //modify the first cells frame or bounds

}
```